# Receiving a 'BREAK' in tcl 8.5.1 causes COM port to quit working (win xp)

Tags: serial-port, tcl

I'm working on a program which makes heavy use of a serial port.

It is currently a windows-only program (unfortunately :-), running on Windows XP.  The TCL version is 8.5.1.0 - it may or may not be an 'official' TCL, not sure.

Everything works perfectly until the device on the other end sends a BREAK (or, just disconnect the serial port :-).

Once that happens, data is still received fine, but sending data to the port via 'puts' results in no data going to the serial port.  In fact, when I do send a character, asking fconfigure for the last error, it always says BREAK.  Now, I don't know if that's just leftovers from the previous error or not.

In any case, HOW in the world does someone clear the 'break' condition on a serial port in TCL?

Thanks!

Rusty

Update:  here's how we open the serial port:

```
    set state(com_port_handle) [open $name r+]


    #      Configure the COM port.

    fconfigure $state(com_port_handle) -mode 115200,n,8,1 \
                                       -blocking 0 \
                                       -buffering none \
                                       -translation binary
    fconfigure $state(com_port_handle) -handshake none
```

When we want to force a break from our side, we do:

```
    fconfigure $state(com_port_handle) -ttycontrol {break 1}
    after 100
    fconfigure $state(com_port_handle) -ttycontrol {break 0}
```

Comment: Well, I do not yet know how to clear this condition, but I have discovered that if you do NOT use xonxoff mode the condition never happens.

Rusty

Comment: When you say a BREAK do you mean a NUL/0x00/CTRL-@ character?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the BREAK condition using -ttycontrol option of the open command?

Comment: In answer to the first question, no I mean a break condition - that's where the serial line is held in an active state for longer than a character time (actually, usually MUCH longer), with no bit toggles.


In answer to the second, no I've not tried that in the open command.  Above is our code around the open, for reference.

When we want to SEND a break, you see our code above, so I'd assumed that the ttycontrol on open would do the same thing - send a break, not enable it.

I'll have to try ttycontrol and see what happens - I'll update here when I've had a chance.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [this summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) of software flow control, it looks like sending the `Xon` character might wake the link back up (if it indeed was paused by an `Xoff`).

Also, you might want to take a look at [these](http://wiki.tcl.tk/447) [articles](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1108) on the TCLer's wiki regarding serial ports.  This is the code I normally use as a skeleton for anything involving a serial port.